how to compare 2 or more elements in a list with integers of more than 2 digits
i have user input for list elements. any number of elements user can be entered.
if the user enters 3 elements in the list
and if the user entered the elements as follows
123456789
123467890
123489012
how to find the how many digits are matched from starting using python?
output will be : 4 ( because all elements 4 digits are same (1234))
if the user enters 4 elements in the list
and if the user entered the elements as follows
123456789
123467890
123489012
123589000
how to find the how many digits are matched from starting using python?
output will be : 3 ( because all elements 3 digits are same (123))

Perhaps you can use a for loop:
import locale
from collections.abc import Sequence

def _get_decimal_separator() -> str:
  """Returns the locale-specific decimal separator."""
  locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
  conv = locale.localeconv()
  return str(conv['decimal_point']) if conv['decimal_point'] else '.'

def _normalize_number(num: str, decimal_seperator: str) -> str:
  """Normalizes a number string to remove minus sign and decimal separator."""
  return num.lstrip('-').replace(decimal_seperator, '')

def common_prefix_length(numbers: Sequence[str]) -> int:
  """Finds number of matching starting digits across all elements in sequence.
  
  Args:
    numbers: A sequence of string representations of numbers.

  Returns:
    The count of matching digits from the beginning across all elements.
  """
  if not numbers:
    return 0
  decimal_separator = _get_decimal_separator()
  numbers = [_normalize_number(num, decimal_separator) for num in numbers]
  reference = numbers[0]
  for i in range(len(reference)):
    for number in numbers[1:]:
      if i >= len(number) or number[i] != reference[i]:
        return i
  return len(reference)

def main() -> None:
  user_input = input('Enter numbers separated by spaces: ').split()
  if len(user_input) == 0:
    print('No numbers provided.')
    return
  print(f'{common_prefix_length(user_input) = }')

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()

Example Usage 1:
Enter numbers separated by spaces: 123456789 123467890 123489012
common_prefix_length(user_input) = 4

Example Usage 2:
Enter numbers separated by spaces: 123456789 123467890 123489012 123589000
common_prefix_length(user_input) = 3

Example Usage 3:
Enter numbers separated by spaces: 12.3 -12.3 123 -123
common_prefix_length(user_input) = 3

Example Usage 4:
Enter numbers separated by spaces: 3 2 4
common_prefix_length(user_input) = 0

Example Usage 5:
Enter numbers separated by spaces: 1 12 123
common_prefix_length(user_input) = 1


sinha ji thank you very much for your quick reply.  i am novice in the field of python programming. is there any way to simplify this code for new comer to understand. it is working well. Further more, the inputs given by the user shall be equal  number of digits. then only this code is processed. if the user entered different number of digit in each case it will end.

I'm curious which part is complicated? This would be good feedback for my supposed "Python Readability". If you don't need to support negative number or non-integers you can delete: decimal_separator = _get_decimal_separator(),
numbers = [_normalize_number(num, decimal_separator) for num in numbers] and the corresponding two helper functions: _normalize_number, _get_decimal_separator?

Further more, the inputs given by the user shall be equal number of digits. then only this code is processed. if the user entered different number of digit in each case it will end. Yeah the most common prefix cannot be longer than the shortest number in the sequence? See example 5 and let me know if that is not what you expect?

thank so much sinha ji. i deleted as you said. it is ok . The fifth example will be rejected by printing -1 or some thing else. further,  single digit (ie example 4 )  also not accepted.
